# Probability calculation. Match people and outfit

Tags: probability

Here's the scenario:
There are $12$ people and $12$ different outfits. A stranger guesses which outfit belongs to which person.

How would I go about calculating the probability for specific outcomes? So, e.g., what is the probability that the person guesses the correct outfit for $4$ people?

My ideas so far:
This should be drawing without replacement, since we cannot assign an outfit twice.

There are $12x12=144$ possibilities. So to guess all $12$ correct, there's a $1/144$ chance, to get $11$ correct, there's a $12/144$ chance.

So far, I'm really struggling putting that into an equation, so I wouldn't know how to get the possibilities for i.e. $10$ correct matches, etc.

Would gladly appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that there are $12!$ ways to assign outfits to people, not $144$ as you suggest.  I recommend:  work this out for a smaller number, like $3$ people.  For larger numbers, you will need to work with [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: Basically, for each number $n$, calculate the number of distinct $n$-tuples and by the number of derangements on $12-n$.

Comment: See also [partial derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers).